# Scraping weather data from an archive

Tags: python, web-scraping, weather

I am trying to scrape weather data from the following weblink for the years 2020-2023: https://www.windguru.cz/archive.php?id_spot=4910&id_model=3&date_from=2020-08-01&date_to=2023-08-01. The data of particular interest are wind directions, which are indicated here by arrows. However, I'd like the underlying angles that were used to produce these arrows. The website requires an email login to see this data, so I have tried to use selenium in Python for this purpose:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.windguru.cz/archive.php?id_spot=4910&id_model=3&date_from=2020-08-01&date_to=2023-08-01')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#forecasts-page")))
```

What do I need to add to this code to extract the desired information? I am inexperienced with programming, so a lot of this is new to me. If someone could finish the code or provide an alternative to extract the angular data of interest, then that would be excellent.

Comment: Why Not using there API https://stations.windguru.cz/json_api_stations.html you could u request libary to Fetch this data. No selenium needed ;)

Comment: Could you demonstrate how this could work in Python, please? I have no experience with APIs

Comment: Below an example of an Basic wrapper for the api

Answer (score 1):

Here's Just an basic Python wrapper for the Windguru Station JSON API. I dont have an Account so you need to Test this Code by yourself.

```py
import requests

class WindguruAPIWrapper:
    def __init__(self, uid, password):
        self.base_url = "https://www.windguru.cz/int/wgsapi.php"
        self.uid = uid
        self.password = password
        self.default_params = {
            "uid": self.uid,
            "password": self.password,
            "format": "json"
        }

    def get_data_current(self):
        params = dict(self.default_params, q="station_data_current")
        response = requests.get(self.base_url, params=params)
        return response.json()

    def get_data(self, from_time=None, to_time=None, avg_minutes=10, vars_list=None):
        params = dict(self.default_params, q="station_data", avg_minutes=avg_minutes)
        if from_time:
            params["from"] = from_time
        if to_time:
            params["to"] = to_time
        if vars_list:
            params["vars"] = ",".join(vars_list)
        
        response = requests.get(self.base_url, params=params)
        return response.json()

    def get_data_csv(self, from_time=None, to_time=None, avg_minutes=10, vars_list=None):
        params = dict(self.default_params, q="station_data_csv", avg_minutes=avg_minutes)
        if from_time:
            params["from"] = from_time
        if to_time:
            params["to"] = to_time
        if vars_list:
            params["vars"] = ",".join(vars_list)
        
        response = requests.get(self.base_url, params=params)
        return response.text

    def get_data_last(self, hours=1, avg_minutes=10, back_hours=0, vars_list=None):
        params = dict(self.default_params, q="station_data_last", hours=hours, back_hours=back_hours)
        if vars_list:
            params["vars"] = ",".join(vars_list)
        
        response = requests.get(self.base_url, params=params)
        return response.json()

    def get_data_last_csv(self, hours=1, avg_minutes=10, back_hours=0, vars_list=None):
        params = dict(self.default_params, q="station_data_last_csv", hours=hours, back_hours=back_hours)
        if vars_list:
            params["vars"] = ",".join(vars_list)
        
        response = requests.get(self.base_url, params=params)
        return response.text

# Replace with your actual UID and password
uid = "YOUR_UID"
password = "YOUR_PASSWORD"

api = WindguruAPIWrapper(uid, password)
current_data = api.get_data_current()
print(current_data)

# You can use similar calls for other methods provided by the API wrapper
```

Remember to install the `requests` library if you haven't already by running `pip install requests` in your terminal.